# Use variable in parameter ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to check if param key exists with a variable name and if it exists I want to use value something like params[filenamestring[-1]].

filenamestring is any array generate with split

generally we use params like params[:key] but here i have array and want to use params value with array last element like params[filenamestring[-1]]

Comment: What's the content of `params`, what is `filenamestring`, what do you expect `filenamestring[-1]` to return and what's your expected result?

Comment: filenamestring is array and filenamestring[-1] is string

Comment: And what's the content / value of `params` and the content / value of `filenamestring`?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for this:

```
if params.key?(filenamestring[-1])
```

This will check if the key exists within the params.

Edit: Something like this would add the param to an array:

```
my_array << params[filenamestring[-1]] if params.key?(filenamestring[-1])
```

Or to add it to a string or integer:

```
my_variable + params[filenamestring[-1]] if params.key?(filenamestring[-1])
```

If you are doing something else, let me know and I'll update my answer again.

Comment: Actually I may be getting that confused a bit. Do you want to check the key name or the value? Or both? "with a variable name" is very confusing.

Comment: i want to check first and if key exists i want to get value as well something like params[filenamestring[-1]]

Comment: What do you want to do with the variable when you 'get it'?