# Use params value with variable in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to check if param key exists with a variable name and if it exists I want to use value something like `params[filenamestring[-1]]`.

filenamestring is any array generate with split

Comment: It's completely unclear what you're asking. Please give us an example of your inputs and your expected outputs.

Comment: Params are posted like params[:file_abc] and some other random names.

Comment: @meager sorry but I am not getting how to explain more. but l am trying it again. generally we use params like params[:key] but here i have array and want to use params value with array last element like params[filenamestring[-1]]

Comment: Your previous (identical) question was closed because it was unclear. It's pointless to post the same question again without providing more details.

Comment: That said, please edit your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32565239/477037) and add more details (see the comments).

Comment: I just did it , can you please review it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you variable is a hash than here is your answer

```
if params.has_key?(filenamestring[-1])
  param_value = param[filenamestring[-1]]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check existence of key using `has_key?` method:

```
key = filenamestring[-1]
# or, key = filenamestring.last
if params.has_key?(key)
  value = params[key]
  # do stuff with value
end
```